# Analyzing change points for highly autocorrelated data (Using R package strucchange)

Tags: r, time-series

I have questions about times series regressions that include highly autocorrelated variables.

I have a linear regression model that will be

Yi = bi * Xi + ui

,where at time point i, and Yi: dependant variable, Xi: regressor, bi: regression coefficients, ui: disturbance.

My aim is to find the change points of bi in the model and to segmentize the data based on them.

Therefore, I analyzed data with R package 'strucchange' that includes tests for detecting structural changes.

My data of X and Y are both highly autocorrelated.
The autocorrelation of X seems to affect the autocorrelationess of Y.

I am considering to reduce these autocorrelations by
the regression with lag points for each variable, or using other popular methods.

Can I get reasonable change points of bi if I get rid of autocorrelations of X and Y simulatationally?

Plus, should I do preprocessing the data for removing its autocorrelations before inputing it on `strucchange`?

I found some functions of `strucchange` like `efp` supports options for using a covariance matrix to calculate estimates.

But, I didn't find any options about a covariance matrix for `breakpoints` that cuts time series data based on the change points it detected.

Therefore, I am going to use the process to remove the autocorrelations before using `breakpoints`.

Thank you for your time.

Below graphs show the autocorrelation in my example data.

[image: The autocovariance function for two time series variables]